# Why I'm getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to get an item of jsonArray?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my app I have smth like attaching files to messages. These attached file are shown in RecyclerView with adapter. Each item of RV has it own btn for deleting it. The problem is when I have two items at my list and try to delete 1 item not the 2-nd I'm receiving an error. But when I try to remove 2-nd item and then 1-st everything ok. I used debugger and managed to locate problematic line but I don't know how to solve this problem. So, here is code from adapter for removing item from list:

```
val array = Singleton.array
if (array!!.size() > 0) {
  for (i in 0 until array.size()) {
   val obj = array.get(i).asJsonObject

   if (obj.get("filename").toString().substring(1, obj.get("filename").toString().length - 1) == mNames[position]) {
   array.remove(obj)
   mNames.removeAt(position)
   Singleton.array = array
   updateNames(mNames)
   }

 }
}
```

I have problem at this line:

```
val obj = array.get(i).asJsonObject
```

I checked via logger this variable and everything seems to be ok,  I can get value with 0 index. Then I thought that problem is at the place where I send data to adapter, but everything ok. I used debugger and saw that method getAsJsonObject() throws this exception:

[image]

why does it happen and how I can solve this error. I tried to change this:
`for (i in 0 until array.size())` to this `for (i in 0 until array.size()-1)` and it didn't work. Then I tried to change this loop to this `for (i in 1 until array.size())` and it didn't help also. So, where I made mistake and how I can prevent this problem in future?

P.S. Sorry for attaching screenshot of debugger, because I couldn't get text data from it.

Comment: elements numeration in Java/Kotlin is `0...length-1`so if your array size is 10, you can get 0...9 elements of it. Check your `for (i in 0 until array.size()) {` condition

Comment: You are removing an element from an array while iterating through it so its size changes. Try removing directly from Singleton.array or make a copy of the array for iteration and remove from the original.

Comment: @Arun, can you check my answer please? maybe it will solve my problem?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, I saw that problem is connected with process of removing item from array, it means that my loop continues going when I have already deleted its item, so I decided to use break/return from loop when the item is deleted, my answer shows this method

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko I think your answer should work as long as you are deleting only one item.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, but I can't remove several items, only one single item no group deleting

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko why? you can I'm sure

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, why are you sure? I can delete item when I press delete btn and I can remove only one item from the list? I can't tick several items :)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko do you mean *you can't* or *you don't want to*? Because I see no obstacles to delete multiple items

Comment: I can't, I'm sure, and it also surprise for me that you are sure, because it is also interesting for me how to delete several items :) for example when I already have some items which come from draft message and for deleting draft file I have to send request also to server

Comment: Which class `array` is? If it is a collection, you can use `array.removeAll(<collection to remove>)` method to remove multiple items. Also as `Rajasekaran M` showed, you can use the cycle to remove multiple items

Comment: it is logically approved that I can't remove multiply items, one click=one item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removed element from source array , that's why you getting exception so use new array for your filtered values

Problem at below line

```
array.remove(obj)
```

Solution :

```
val positionsForRemove = ArrayList<Int>(),
val array = Singleton.array
if (array!!.size() > 0) {
   for (i in 0 until array.size()) {
     val obj = array.get(i).asJsonObject
     if (obj.get("filename").toString().substring(1, obj.get("filename").toString().length - 1) == mNames[position]) 
       positionsForRemove.add(position)
    }
   for(position in positionsForRemove){
          array.remove(position)
          mNames.remove(position)   
        }
  Singleton.array = array
  updateNames(mNames)


}
```

Comment: so, where I can insert this new array usage?

Comment: Declare new array or MutableList and add your all array elements into it. and newList.remove(obj); and you can restore it on your singleton after complete for loop

Comment: but what about return after deleting the array item? can it help me? or array declaration is better?

Comment: yes I have updated answer now try with it. for loop { was misplaced.now it's will work for you

Comment: so is it better than my solution which I posted below? your solution is also working good but why is it better?

Comment: I think yes, because your code will generate error or crash when you have more than one item in your list. because you  are removed item from  array inside for . it's not good because you should not do read and write operation in same list at for loop

Answer (score 3):

You are using remove method inside the for loop iteration which is dynamically change array size.

If you need to remove only one item then refer @Jeeva's answer.

If you want to remove multiple positions from list at a time, you have to refer below method to remove item from array, .

```
val removePositions = ArrayList<Int>(),
val array = Singleton.array
if (array!!.size() > 0) {
  for (i in 0 until array.size()) {
   val obj = array.get(i).asJsonObject

   if (obj.get("filename").toString().substring(1, obj.get("filename").toString().length - 1) == mNames[position])
   //array.remove(obj)
   //mNames.removeAt(position)
   removePositions.add(position)
   //Singleton.array = array
   //updateNames(mNames)
  }

  for (i in 0 until removePositions.size()) {
    array.remove(removePositions[i])
    mNames.remove(removePositions[i])
  }
  Singleton.array = array
  updateNames(mNames)
}
```

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, what is the error you are getting with above code?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, sorry code was bit miss-placed. Now try with fixed code.

Answer (score 1):

Just add break statement inside the if condition.

```
val array = Singleton.array
if (array!!.size() > 0) {
  for (i in 0 until array.size()) {
   val obj = array.get(i).asJsonObject

   if (obj.get("filename").toString().substring(1, obj.get("filename").toString().length - 1) == mNames[position]) {
   array.remove(obj)
   mNames.removeAt(position)
   Singleton.array = array
   updateNames(mNames)
   break;
   }

 }
}
```

The reason your are getting exception after  removing first element is the loop gets executed after removing first element.
But if you had break,it wont execute next time.
The reason you are not getting exception when you try to remove second element is the loop ends exactly after removing the second element.

Answer (score 0):

Dear friends it seems that I managed to solve this problem but I'm not sure so I need your checking. So, I added return statement in my condition:

```
if (obj.get("filename").toString().substring(1, obj.get("filename").toString().length - 1) == mNames[position]) {
array.remove(obj)
mNames.removeAt(position)
Singleton.array = array
updateNames(mNames)
return@setButton
}
```

so when I meet this condition I return from process of deleting. I think that I know why my app has been crashing sometimes - I press yes btn at my alert dialog and my object was removed from array but my loop continue working and checking. But maybe I'm wrong again :)

Comment: just use break statement bro.

Comment: where? instead of return?

Comment: yes you are using this code for the delete button which will be used once right after removing why should you continue iterating the for loop.Just use break once the if condition is executed

Comment: and my method can solve this problem or users above also gave useful advice?

Comment: I'd suggest you doing other way: Instead of *on-the-;fly* removing items from the array, first collect the items to be removed into another array, and only after the cycle - remove the items

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko the above code is for his delete button which is present in all recycler view holder so there is no need for collecting items which needs to be deleted.